Sign assemblies inside nuget package with Azure Key Vault in Azure Devops pipeline
Goal is to create nuget packages that contain the compiled C# assemblies code signed  with a certificate that is stored in an Azure Key Vault during CI/CD build with a Azure Devops YAML pipeline.
I tried several approaches in an automated pipeline, but none of them needs 100% my needs:

nuget packages are generated as part of the build (SDK style project)
Sign (pure) assemblies with AzureSignTool after they were built
Sign nuget package (but not the assemblies inside) with NugetSignTool

Is there a way to code sign the assembly after the build, but before packing it? Or is there a tool that can sign the assmeblies "inside" the nupkg?

May I assume your expected workflow is to Build assembly only -> Sign the assembly with cert retrieved from Azure KV -> Run dotnet pack to generate .nupkg package? If my understanding is correct, what has blocked you from doing so? Or your actual expectation is to have the nuget packages not to be generated with build?

No, my expected workflow is to build a project with true, so a nuget package is built without additional efforts.

So you mean you expect to build the projects with nuget package generated during the build -> then sign each assembly inside that package without repackaging? Please correct me if there is any misunderstanding. But before integrating the workflow in Azure DevOps pipelines, do we know if it is even possible by dotnet CLI or any 3rd party tool?

I guess the answer below doesn't meet your requirement as it needs to run dotnet pack after code sign, right? let's see if some experts can share how to sign assemblies inside a nupkg.

Correct. I'm looking for a tool that can sign inside the nupkg... If there's no other solution I could of course extract, sign and zip it againg. Probably the best would be to integrate the (key vault) signing process directly in the build. Then the assemblies in the out directory were also signed.  Updated that in the question. The answer below is not what I'm looking for.

A wild guess is even the tool exists, it may also adopt the workflow to extract -> sign -> repack. Thanks for the clarification anyway.

By the way, would you consider the solution in this thread, which will transparently and automatically sign the assemblies you reference as part of the build process. StrongNamer

You can use PowershellTask@5 to sign your packages an use the YAML code below:-
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  azureKeyVaultName: 'valleykeyvault3'
  azureKeyVaultCertificateName: 'valleycert'
  azureSubscription: '01xxxxxxxx7cb2a7'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '2.2.x'
        
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
        KeyVaultName: '$(azureKeyVaultName)'
        SecretsFilter: '$(azureKeyVaultCertificateName)'
        RunAsPreJob: false

    - script: |
        dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool --version 5.0.0
        dotnet add package SignTool --version 10.0.17763.132
      displayName: 'Install Signing Tools'
    
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          $certThumbprint = (Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $(azureKeyVaultName) -Name $(azureKeyVaultCertificateName)).Thumbprint
          $secureKeyVaultAccessToken = (az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net).accessToken
          $certPfxPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cert.pfx"
          
          # Extract the certificate from Azure Key Vault to a file
          az keyvault secret download --file $certPfxPath --vault-name $(azureKeyVaultName) --name $(azureKeyVaultCertificateName)
          
          # Sign the assemblies
          $assemblies = Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -Filter "*.dll" -Recurse
          foreach ($assembly in $assemblies) {
              & '$(USERPROFILE)\.dotnet\tools\azuresigntool.exe' sign -kvu https://$(azureKeyVaultName).vault.azure.net -kvi $(azureKeyVaultCertificateName) -tr http://timestamp.digicert.com -v -in $assembly.FullName -out $assembly.FullName
          }
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
      displayName: 'Code Sign Assemblies'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'pack'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - powershell: |
        $nugetPackages = Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Filter "*.nupkg"
        foreach ($package in $nugetPackages) {
            & '$(USERPROFILE)\.dotnet\tools\nugetsigntool.exe' sign -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint -InputPath $package.FullName
        }
      displayName: 'Sign NuGet Packages'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

Output:-


Updated yaml:-
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  azureKeyVaultName: 'valleykeyvault3'
  azureKeyVaultCertificateName: 'valleycert'
  azureSubscription: '0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '2.2.x'
        
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
        KeyVaultName: '$(azureKeyVaultName)'
        SecretsFilter: '$(azureKeyVaultCertificateName)'
        RunAsPreJob: false

    - script: |
        dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool --version 5.0.0
        dotnet add package SignTool --version 10.0.17763.132
      displayName: 'Install Signing Tools'
    
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          $certThumbprint = (Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $(azureKeyVaultName) -Name $(azureKeyVaultCertificateName)).Thumbprint
          $secureKeyVaultAccessToken = (az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net).accessToken
          $certPfxPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cert.pfx"
      
          # Extract the certificate from Azure Key Vault to a file
          az keyvault secret download --file $certPfxPath --vault-name $(azureKeyVaultName) --name $(azureKeyVaultCertificateName)
          
          # Sign the assemblies
          $assemblies = Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -Filter "*.dll" -Recurse
          foreach ($assembly in $assemblies) {
              & '$(USERPROFILE)\.dotnet\tools\azuresigntool.exe' sign -kvu https://$(azureKeyVaultName).vault.azure.net -kvi $(azureKeyVaultCertificateName) -tr http://timestamp.digicert.com -v -in $assembly.FullName -out $assembly.FullName
          }
      displayName: 'Code Sign Assemblies'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'pack'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - powershell: |
        $nugetPackages = Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Filter "*.nupkg"
        foreach ($package in $nugetPackages) {
            & '$(USERPROFILE)\.dotnet\tools\nugetsigntool.exe' sign -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint -InputPath $package.FullName
        }
      displayName: 'Sign NuGet Packages'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'


I have these steps already in pipelines working. The question is how to sign an existing nupkg (because it's generated with GeneratePackageOnBuild=true) or how to execute the signing process within the build process right after the assembly is built.

Check my updated yaml code in the answer
